# javascript - rollover effect on overlapping transparent images

Tags: javascript

I want to add rollover effect on overlapping transparent images.

For example:

The following image is divided into 5 parts and I want to add rollover effect (different image) on each of them

[image]

When O tried with div or img tag, the image is rendered as a rectangle so rollover effect is not proper. When i rollover on green part between yellow, the yellow image gets highlighted because its z-index is high.

Following is the code that I tried:

```
<body>
<br />
<img src="part1.png" onclick="console.log('test1');"/>
<img src="part2.png" onclick="console.log('test2');" style="position:absolute; left:30px; top: 19px;"/>
<img src="part3.png" onclick="console.log('test3');" style="position:absolute; left:70px; top: 15px;"/>
<img src="part4.png" onclick="console.log('test4');" style="position:absolute; left:95px; top: 16px;"/>
<img src="part5.png" onclick="console.log('test5');" style="position:absolute; left:123px; top: 24px;"/>    
</body>
```

images => [image: part1], [image: part2], [image: part3], [image: part4], [image: part5]

I don't want to use jQuery, if possible.

Comment: jQUery doesn't really help for this problem, you need a drawing library like Raphael.js

Comment: Thanks for replying. This is not a drawing. Its just an example to explain my problem. All the 5 parts are images. Regards

Comment: Can't you post an example of the code? It really helps brainstorming

Comment: If I understand from your comment on the answer, you do NOT want to use an imagemap? The very purpose of an image map is to identify irregularly-shaped areas so you can do stuff when such an area is entered. Without a map, there is no direct way for the client to know when the mouse has entered part of an irregularly-shaped area. I mean theoretically you could use javascript to inspect the actual image data and see if it's a transparent pixel or not, but that would be much more difficult and unreliable. Whatever your map is - taking the time to make in imagemap will be well invested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Kolink and others for their responses. I tried to create image map as Kolink suggested but it was too difficult and also if i made a slight change to the image, then i would have to create a new image map.

I replaced this part with a **flash swf** file. It was far easier for me to create this kind of thing in flash.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did this sort of thing is to place all the image elements, then put one big invisible (transparent) image over the top ("big" in the CSS, the file is actually 1x1 pixel). Then apply an imagemap to the topmost image. Result can be seen here: http://pokefarm.org/

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. Your idea is good but i have a MAP which would be very complicated to implement image map. Regards